# Retrieving my Google Calendar events with a PHP script ran by Cron

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, cron, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I'd like fetch my Google Calendar events with a PHP script that is ran by Cron on every 15 minutes. I've seen that there are some questions like this already asked but they're without answers and I do not prefer to create a service account.

I'm currently using a script that I wrote by following this tutorial https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php, but the problem is that after a few hours of retrieving data the script wants me to open an OAuth2 link, give access to the app again and enter the verification code. This doesn't work for me as I'd like to give the script access to my account and from that point on it should run without any human interaction.

The tutorial states that the authorization flow is designed for CLI applications (which a PHP Cron script is in my opinion, am I wrong?) and that for Web app authorization you need to implement OAuth2.

Is there a way to get the current CLI authorization working or do I need to implement OAuth2 for my Cron script?

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#offline)?

Comment: Yes, something similar. I actually have this access type set to offline. I figured it out actually, need to post an answer to question. The point is that the example on Google Developers doesn't refresh tokens at all but demands an authorization code every time to get a new access code which in a no-go for me. I was playing around a bit and discovered authenticate() function that returns both tokens, access and refresh.

Comment: Did you find the authenticate() in the docs? Can you link?

Comment: It would be great if you could post your solution.

Comment: No, I found someone mentioning it on StackOverflow so I checked the PHP Google API Client and OAuth2 files and found this authenticate() function.

I will post the solution shortly, as soon as I have a bit of free time.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the Google Calendar quickstart example doesn't not use refresh tokens, so I played around a bit and took care of it by myself. When the script is ran for the first time you must still open the link and get the auth code. After that the script takes care of tokens by itself.

So basically what I did is that I replaced the *$client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($auth_code)* with *$client->authenticate($auth_code)*. The difference is that the first function returns only access code and other meta data regarding that code, while the second function returns refresh token as well. When you receive the full JSON object that contains access and refresh tokens you must just write it to *token.json* file and that's it.

The code I wrote is this one:

```
    $credentials = array();

    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
        $credentials = $accessToken;
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $new_credentials = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
            $new_credentials["refresh_token"] = $credentials["refresh_token"];
            $credentials = $new_credentials;
        } else {
            try {
                // Request authorization from the user.
                $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
                printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
                print 'Enter verification code: ';

                $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));
                $credentials = $client->authenticate($authCode);
                $accessToken = $credentials["access_token"];
                $refreshToken = $credentials["refresh_token"];

                // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
                $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

                // Check to see if there was an error.
                if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                error_log($e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }

        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($credentials));
    }
```

Comment: [Reference Section 5](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/2ab61398fa6c7e319f3665fbf0c01df6f1f683ec/docs/oauth-web.md#step-5-exchange-authorization-code-for-refresh-and-access-tokens)